# Offsite data backups and data vaulting... 

Tags: backup, rsync, incremental-backup

This is for website data, database data, and some internal office data that needs to be "vaulted" and secured.

Any viable "experts only" solutions out there that don't require ridiculous time to setup and maintain and also are very cost effective?

rsync ability is preferred.

Currently there is 5TB data to vault and per rsync job every 24 hours, about 150GB is updated.

Comment: Vaulted as in offsite, encrypted, physically locked, what?

What do you mean by requiring an "experts only" solution?

Comment: Well something like the target market for slicehost is for VPS. No cruft, simple interface, and requires someone who knows wtf they are doing to just use the very simple UI. 

The data "vaulting" is just an off-site backup that may or may not be encrypted, but from the public server that data is sent to (or pulled into) it is then sent to another server farm that only the public server has access to, or in this case, a "vault".

Comment: Need more detail to answer the question. Do you need snapshotting on the remote site? What do you consider cost effective? How much do you want to do yourself, how much must the system provide? If you're just looking for an offsite copy then there are dozens of decent providers out there..

Answer (score 0):

Use RAID 5/6/1.
Use ecryptfs on the remote server to encrypt directories hosting the information. Mount the eCryptFS folder, and rsync -avhe the data to the remote server. Unmount the eCryptFS folder.